# Why I can't capture connections with fiddler on hbservice.com

Tags: fiddler

I can't capture connections on hbservice.com?

I got an error:

> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Why? How can I capture requests on this site? I have enabled to capture SSL requests on Fiddler. But it don't worked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear here, `hbservice.com` is not an active website; `https://www.hbservice.com/` is. I don't have trouble capturing this site with Fiddler.

The server in question *requires* TLS/1.1 or TLS/1.2 which means it won't work with many clients; you will need to use Fiddler4 and enable TLS/1.1 to capture traffic to this site. Enable these protocols inside Fiddler's Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS > Enabled Protocols link.